# C++ -- Storing from .txt file to array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

2 Questions:

The first question is, I need to input the name of the text file when the program runs so let's say it's called "Banana.txt" , I type it in and I'm missing the last word of the file.  This is basically all I used to output from the txt file.

```
while(File.good()){
    cout <<word << " "; //put spaces in between the words
    File >> word; }
```

Not sure how to get the last word.

The second question is how do I store the information from the .txt file into an array that I can use later?
Does it have to be multidimensional?   The maximum words in the file are 100..
Eventually I'm going to need to ignore any words < 4 characters.

I actually can't recall if I should use char or string.   But iirc char is each individual character whereas string is a collection of characters?  Arg.  Scratch that, Looking it up in a bit..

Not allowed to use hash_, vectors, maps, stack, or lists so I'm not sure how to go about this problem

Thanks in advance for the help. I tried looking through other threads but I'm not sure if those are the ones I'm looking for... Sorry for the questions ..

Comment: How about switching lines 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, you need to first read into the word then output it.

The "intuitive" loop of `while(File.good())` though is flawed because if you are at end of file but haven't read it yet, the stream will appear good until you try reading the next word.

As a result the read will fail. You could do

```
while( File.good() )
{
   if( File >> word )
   {
     // process this word
   }
}
```

but simpler is

```
 while( File >> word )
 {
     // process the word
 }
```

Another thing you can use is istream_iterator and copy, and then you can actually copy them into your sequence. However you are not allowed to use the standard C++ library.

Comment: Lol.  I accidentally had a random File>word before the loop.  Hence, it would already have read the first word .  Thanks for helping me realize my mistake though.

Answer (score 1):

You're outputting before you've input.
Try swapping your two lines in the `while` loop, something like:

```
while(File.good())
{    
    File >> word;
    cout << word << " "; //put spaces in between the words
}
```

to put the data into a container, assuming `word` is of type `string`, try:

```
vector<string> v;
```

and at the bottom of your loop:

```
v.push_back(word);
```

Comment: ha ha you just copied my comment into your answer. Actually your answer isn't quite correct..